# Selenium Multithreading with two webdriver instances but only execute in one instance

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiple-instances

I wrote a class to create a instance of Selenium webdriver then scrap some data. Everything works fine in single thread but when I try switching to multithread all operation only execute in one browser, the another one launched but nothing happened.

Here is my multithread code

```
def run_downloader(account, date_range, company_name, invoice_type):
    downloader = InvoiceDownloaderEnchanted(account=account,
                                            date_range=date_range,
                                            company_name=company_name,
                                            invoice_type=invoice_type)
    downloader.start_webdriver()
    downloader.process()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        executor.map(run_downloader,
                     repeat((cfg.USERNAME, cfg.PASSWORD)),
                     repeat(('01/08/2022', '31/08/2022')),
                     repeat('Company Name'),
                     [InvoiceType.INWARD, InvoiceType.OUTWARD])
```

And there is my webdriver Class init code:

```
class InvoiceDownloaderEnchanted:
def __init__(self,
             account,
             company_name: str,
             invoice_type: InvoiceType,
             date_range: tuple | None = None,
             target_url: str | None = cfg.WEBSITE_URL
             ):
    self.account = account
    self.company_name = company_name
    self.invoice_type = invoice_type
    self.date_range = date_range
    self.target_url = target_url
    self.driver = None
   
def start_webdriver(self):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_prefs = cfg.CHROME_PREFS
    chrome_prefs['download.default_directory'] = self.download_folder
    print(chrome_prefs['download.default_directory'])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', chrome_prefs)
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    user_agent = UserAgent().random
    chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                                   options=chrome_options)
    print(self.driver)
    self.driver.maximize_window()

def process(self):
    # Do scrapping stuffs
```

After some debug, i notice that `download.default_directory` of two instances are different (as i expected) when i `print(chrome_prefs['download.default_directory'])` but is the same in `chrome_options.experimental_options`.
I checked two webdriver instances and `driver.capabilities['chrome']['userDataDir]` are also different:

```
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="93cef277d1796c241cb75f729dec222f")>
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="de08b1c6baad30587717082e41c294b5")>
```

Sometimes i run the code, it only open one browser. I think the problem is two webdriver instance is reference to one variable or something like that, but have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by remove argument `chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")` from start_webdrive